# Заголовок захватил в плен всё меню навигации

Tags: css, вёрстка

Выполняю тренировочный пример, и столкнулся с проблемой, что после того как  семантический тег завершился и пошла вторая секция promo. Заголовок в ней совершенно наглым образом прописывается на навигационном меню и даже кнопки не стесняется, прямо поверх кнопки прописывается(здесь через сниппет этого невидно, наверное не знаю как подключить шрифты Roboto сюда, на скриншоте приложенном во всех красках видна проблема). Почему не работает? Используется Bootstrap

```css
* {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

header {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #212121;
  z-index: 5;
}

.hamburger {
  display: none;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 13px 70px;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.menu_link {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
.menu_link:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #1eacc7;
}

.menu_item {
  border-right: 2px dotted black;
  padding-right: 28px;
}
.menu_item:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

.subheader {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 84px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.subheader_logo {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-top: 16px;
}

.subheader_official {
  margin-top: 6px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.subheader_call {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-top: 19px;
  text-align: right;
}

.subheader_phone {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 8px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: right;
  line-height: 12px;
}

.subheader_btn {
  margin-top: 19px;
  width: 172px;
  height: 46px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #1eacc7 0%, #4ce2ff 100%);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.21);
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.subheader_btn:hover {
  background-image: none;
  background-color: #1eacc7;
}

.promo {
  min-height: 800px;
  background: url("https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2021/4/11/f418023a1c0e9994472190ff721cd355-full.jpg") center center/cover no-repeat;
}

.promo_header {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.promo_subheader {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 36px;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 22px;
  text-align: center;
}

.promo_descr {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 23px;
}

.promo_btn {
  display: block;
  margin: 118px auto 0 auto;
  width: 259px;
  height: 63px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #1eacc7 0%, #4ce2ff 100%);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.21);
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.promo_btn:hover {
  background-image: none;
  background-color: #1eacc7;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,700&amp;subset=cyrillic-ext" rel="stylesheet">
 
   <header>
        <nav>
            <div class="container">
                <ul class="menu">
                    <li class="menu_item"><a href="#" class="menu_link">Главная</a></li>
                    <li class="menu_item"><a href="#" class="menu_link">Со своим автомобилем</a></li>
                    <li class="menu_item"><a href="#" class="menu_link">На автомобиле компании</a></li>
                    <li class="menu_item"><a href="#" class="menu_link">Требования</a></li>
                    <li class="menu_item"><a href="#" class="menu_link">Контакты</a></li>
                    <li class="menu_item"><a href="#" class="menu_link">Оставить заявку</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="hamburger">
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="subheader">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-6 col-md-4 offset-md-1">
                        <a href="#" class="subheader_logo"><img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2021/4/11/4ef3cdfe37d551d4e75fb29eae407ad9-full.png" alt="logo"></a>
                        <div class="subheader_official">Официальный партнер Uber в Москве</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="xs-hidden col-md-3 offset-md-1 col-xl-2 offset-xl-2">
                        <div class="subheader_call">Звоните нам ежедневно</div>
                        <a href="tel:84957970988" class="subheader_phone">8 495 797 09 88</a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
                        <a href="tel:84957970988" class="xs-visible subheader_phone">8 495 797 09 88</a>
                        <button class="subheader_btn">заказать звонок</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </header>

    <section class="promo">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 offset-md-0 col-lg-10 offset-lg-1">
                    <h1 class="promo_header">КОМПАНИЯ UBER PARTNERS!</h1>
                    <h2 class="promo_subheader">ПРИГЛАШАЕМ ВОДИТЕЛЕЙ! НА СВОЕМ АВТО!</h2>
                    <div class="promo_descr">
                        Компания UBER динамически развивающаяся. Компания на рынке занимает лидирующее место среди
                        таксомоторных компаний, Компания абсолютно прозрачная вы можете контролировать все процессы у
                        себя в личном кабинете. Бонуcная система.Помимо выполненной работы по заказам, компания
                        начисляет бонусы за
                        пиковое время.
                        <br><br>
                        Мы одни из партнеров и зарекомендовали себя как одна из лучших команд в городе Москве. Водители
                        у нас
                        зарабатывают от 80000- 120000 в месяц.
                    </div>
                    <button class="promo_btn">ОТПРАВИТЬ ЗАЯВКУ!</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это связанно с тем, что вы фиксированно задаете высоту 50 пиксилей ВСЕМУ хедеру.

'+ более логично subheader делать не частью хедера, а внутри Вашего промо блока. Прижатым к верху и добавив padding.

```css
* {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

header {
  position: relative;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #212121;
  z-index: 5;
  top: 0;
}

.hamburger {
  display: none;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 13px 70px;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.menu_link {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
.menu_link:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #1eacc7;
}

.menu_item {
  border-right: 2px dotted black;
  padding-right: 28px;
}
.menu_item:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

.subheader {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 85px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.subheader_logo {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-top: 16px;
}

.subheader_official {
  margin-top: 6px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.subheader_call {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-top: 19px;
  text-align: right;
}

.subheader_phone {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 8px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: right;
  line-height: 12px;
}

.subheader_btn {
  margin-top: 19px;
  width: 172px;
  height: 46px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #1eacc7 0%, #4ce2ff 100%);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.21);
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.subheader_btn:hover {
  background-image: none;
  background-color: #1eacc7;
}

.promo {
  min-height: 800px;
  background: url("https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2021/4/11/f418023a1c0e9994472190ff721cd355-full.jpg") center center/cover no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding-top: 100px;
}

.promo_header {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.promo_subheader {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 36px;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 22px;
  text-align: center;
}

.promo_descr {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 23px;
}

.promo_btn {
  display: block;
  margin: 118px auto 0 auto;
  width: 259px;
  height: 63px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #1eacc7 0%, #4ce2ff 100%);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.21);
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.promo_btn:hover {
  background-image: none;
  background-color: #1eacc7;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,700&amp;subset=cyrillic-ext" rel="stylesheet">
 
   <header>
        <nav>
            <div class="container">
                <ul class="menu">
                    <li class="menu_item"><a href="#" class="menu_link">Главная</a></li>
                    <li class="menu_item"><a href="#" class="menu_link">Со своим автомобилем</a></li>
                    <li class="menu_item"><a href="#" class="menu_link">На автомобиле компании</a></li>
                    <li class="menu_item"><a href="#" class="menu_link">Требования</a></li>
                    <li class="menu_item"><a href="#" class="menu_link">Контакты</a></li>
                    <li class="menu_item"><a href="#" class="menu_link">Оставить заявку</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="hamburger">
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
            </div>
        </nav>
        
    </header>
    
    

    <section class="promo">
        <div class="subheader">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-6 col-md-4 offset-md-1">
                        <a href="#" class="subheader_logo"><img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2021/4/11/4ef3cdfe37d551d4e75fb29eae407ad9-full.png" alt="logo"></a>
                        <div class="subheader_official">Официальный партнер Uber в Москве</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="xs-hidden col-md-3 offset-md-1 col-xl-2 offset-xl-2">
                        <div class="subheader_call">Звоните нам ежедневно</div>
                        <a href="tel:84957970988" class="subheader_phone">8 495 797 09 88</a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
                        <a href="tel:84957970988" class="xs-visible subheader_phone">8 495 797 09 88</a>
                        <button class="subheader_btn">заказать звонок</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 offset-md-0 col-lg-10 offset-lg-1">
                    <h1 class="promo_header">КОМПАНИЯ UBER PARTNERS!</h1>
                    <h2 class="promo_subheader">ПРИГЛАШАЕМ ВОДИТЕЛЕЙ! НА СВОЕМ АВТО!</h2>
                    <div class="promo_descr">
                        Компания UBER динамически развивающаяся. Компания на рынке занимает лидирующее место среди
                        таксомоторных компаний, Компания абсолютно прозрачная вы можете контролировать все процессы у
                        себя в личном кабинете. Бонуcная система.Помимо выполненной работы по заказам, компания
                        начисляет бонусы за
                        пиковое время.
                        <br><br>
                        Мы одни из партнеров и зарекомендовали себя как одна из лучших команд в городе Москве. Водители
                        у нас
                        зарабатывают от 80000- 120000 в месяц.
                    </div>
                    <button class="promo_btn">ОТПРАВИТЬ ЗАЯВКУ!</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```